# Return user data from SID

Tags: powershell, printing

Trying to use SID translator to see what users have permissions on a specific printer (eventually I will modify to use for multiple printers), receiving error You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. Below is what I have.

```
$SID = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::(
(Get-Printer 'Test-Printer-MFP' -Full).PermissionSDDL
)
$User = ($SID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]))

Return $User.Value
```

Update: This function translates the SID to username, I need to do this for all users on the printer so I can query multiple printers.

```
$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier `
("S-1-5-21-3923692831-1208425469-611280938-4396488")
$objUser = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$objUser.Value
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include the _entire_, _exact_ text of the error message.

Comment: Your `$SID` variable is null.

Comment: What do you expect `[System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::()` to do? The `::` operator is for accessing static members of a class. What is the value of the `PermissionSDDL` property?

Comment: I'm trying to get permissions from a printer, I was under the impression that I needed this, if I don't thats fine

Comment: Please answer the second question. What is the value of the `PermissionSDDL` property?

Comment: Ansgar please see my edit

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by that, I'm sorry I wasted your time asking for help

Comment: `(Get-Printer 'Test-Printer-MFP' -Full).PermissionSDDL`. What. Is. Its. Value?

Comment: PS C:\windows\system32> (Get-Printer 'MPLS-DHA-MFP' -Full).PermissionSDDL

G:SYD:(A;;SWRC;;;WD)(A;CIIO;RC;;;AC)(A;OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO;;;AC)(A;;SWRC;;;AC)(A;CIIO;RC;;;CO)(A;OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO;;;CO)(A;OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-3923692831-12084254
69-611280938-4396488)(A;;LCSWSDRCWDWO;;;S-1-5-21-3923692831-1208425469-611280938-4396488)(A;;LCSWSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;OIIO;RPWPSDRCWDWO;;;BA)

PS C:\windows\system32>

Comment: That is the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PermissionSDDL` property gives you a security descriptor in [SDDL format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379567.aspx), not an SID. [ACE strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374928.aspx) in security descriptors of that format contain either string SIDs (*S-x-y-...*) or [SID constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379602.aspx). You could split the string, extract the SIDs, and convert them like you tried in your code. However, that would handle only string SIDs, not SID constants.

A better way to resolve both string SIDs and SID constants to the corresponding names would be to convert the security descriptor from SDDL form to object form. Some quick googling revealed [this article](https://poshscripter.wordpress.com/2017/04/27/sddl-conversion-with-powershell/) using the [`SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59y7ckty.aspx) method for transforming the SDDL string to a "regular" ACL object:

```
Function Convert-SDDLToACL {
    [Cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        #One or more strings of SDDL syntax.
        [string[]]$SDDLString
    )

    foreach ($SDDL in $SDDLString) {
        $ACLObject = New-Object -Type Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity
        $ACLObject.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm($SDDL)
        $ACLObject.Access
    }
}
```

The function returns the ACEs of the generated security descriptor object. You can extract the user/group/principal names from that list like this:

```
$sddl = (Get-Printer 'Test-Printer-MFP' -Full).PermissionSDDL
Convert-SDDLToACL $sddl |
    Select-Object -Expand IdentityReference |
    Select-Object -Expand Value
```